# Auto Rounding From Something While Dividing and Multiplying

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int(main){
std::vector<int> vObj;
        float n = 0.59392;
        int nCopy = n;
        int temNum = 0;;
        while (fmod(nCopy, 1) != 0) {
            temNum = (nCopy * 10); cout << endl << nCopy << endl;
            nCopy *= 10;
            vObj.push_back(temNum);
            cout << "\n\n Cycle\n\n";
            cout << "Temp Num: " << temNum << "\n\nN: " << nCopy << endl;
        }
return 0;
}
```

For example, I input 0.59392 but eventually when the code reaches the bottom, where it should be going
5939.2 and then go to
59392 and stop but for some reason
it keeps going.

Comment: Please explain what the code is supposed to do, I do not get it.

Comment: Your code does not compile. `warning: unnecessary parentheses in declaration of 'main'` - `error: cannot declare '::main' to be a global variable` - `error: expected primary-expression before 'vObj'` - `error: expected '}' before 'vObj'` - `error: expected unqualified-id before 'while'` - `error: expected unqualified-id before 'return'` - `error: expected declaration before '}' token` You should copy exactly the code that reproduces your result.

Comment: You should explain what the code is supposed to do. Without an explanation, I am stuck inferring from the code. And since the code does exactly what it says it does, I've come to the conclusion that it works exactly as I inferred (which is output nothing for that input, once I fixed up the errors -- kind of an opposite of "keeps going").

Comment: Your task could be more accurately solved if you use string operations instead of float: Count the number of digits after dot (`.`). Remove the dot. Remove all leading zero `0`s. (For this solution, it might be worth to care about trailing zeros as well.)

Comment: That's not runnable code. Also in `while (fmod(nCopy, 1) != 0) {`, `nCopy` is an `int`. The loop condition will never be met. Please post code that exhibits the problem you describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yeah , so you have 3 major problems in your code , first of all : it's `int main()` not `int(main)` . second : the variable named **nCopy ** is not supposed to be a integer data type , third one : you have to know what the actual representation of the float number , but first this is my solution for your problem , it's not the best one , but it works for this case :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vObj;
    double n = 0.59392;
    double nCopy = n;
    int temNum = 0;;
    while (fmod(nCopy, 1) != 0) {
        temNum = (nCopy * 10); cout << endl << nCopy << endl;
        nCopy *= 10;
        vObj.push_back(temNum);
        cout << "\n\n Cycle\n\n";
        cout << "Temp Num: " << temNum << "\n\nN: " << nCopy << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

so the explanation is as follow , the double data types gives higher precision than float , that's why I used double instead of float , but it will lack accuracy when the number becomes big .

second of : you have to how is float or double is represented , as the value *0.59392* is actually stored in the memory as value *0.593900024890899658203125* when using float according to IEEE 754 standard , so there are other types of decimals to solve this problem where the difference between them is as follow

- Decimal representation gives lower accuracy but higher range with big numbers and high accuracy when talking about small numbers, most 2 used standards are binary integer decimal (BID) and densely packed decimal (DPD)
- float and doubles gives higher accuracy than Decimal when talking about big numbers but lower range ,they follow IEEE 754 standard
- Fixed-Point types have the lowest range but they are the most accurate one and they are the fastest ones

but unfortunately , C++ only supports float and double types of numbers , but I believe there is external libraries out there to define a decimal data type.